# How to get the video from webcam using v4l2 linux interface?

Tags: c, linux, ioctl, v4l2, v4l

I am trying to [run the sample code](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/userspace-api/v4l/v4l2grab.c.html) from v4l2 API. When I tried to run the sample code, I am facing problem while compiling the program itself. Please check the error, is there something I need to install or flag to pass during the compilation steps?

```
ubox:~/capVideoFrame$ gcc v4l2grab.c && ./a.out
/tmp/cc0E2uRM.o: In function `xioctl':
v4l2grab.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `v4l2_ioctl'
/tmp/cc0E2uRM.o: In function `main':
v4l2grab.c:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `v4l2_open'
v4l2grab.c:(.text+0x30f): undefined reference to `v4l2_mmap'
v4l2grab.c:(.text+0x6a2): undefined reference to `v4l2_munmap'
v4l2grab.c:(.text+0x6c4): undefined reference to `v4l2_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Source code header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include "/usr/include/libv4l2.h" // I am using ubuntu, so pointing to this location
```

Comment: No luck, `gcc -lv4l1 -lv4l2 v4l2grab.c` - same error

Comment: worked! please write it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To successfully compiled you need add flags for it `-lv4l1 -lv4l2`

```
gcc v4l2grab.c -lv4l1 -lv4l2
```

Comment: why we need those flags ?

Comment: It "link" your program with necessary v4l2 libraries

Comment: Please read this article https://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html it will be much clearer why all this is required.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't install libv4l2 before, you need to install it first:

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y libv4l-dev
```

BTW, the above link is dead, the new link is [here](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/userspace-api/v4l/v4l2grab.c.html).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think the OP had already installed the library and the issue was not including the right flags.